# npm outdated only shows devDependencies

Tags: angular, npm, npm-update

Running `npm outdated` shows the following output,

`Package                           Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
@types/jasmine                     2.5.38  2.5.38  2.5.53  cmi-kinvey
@types/node                        6.0.78  6.0.78   8.0.2  cmi-kinvey
ag-grid                             9.1.0   9.1.0  10.1.0  cmi-kinvey
ag-grid-angular                     9.1.0   9.1.0  10.1.0  cmi-kinvey
codelyzer                           2.0.1   2.0.1   3.1.1  cmi-kinvey
jasmine-core                        2.5.2   2.5.2   2.6.4  cmi-kinvey
jasmine-spec-reporter               3.2.0   3.2.0   4.1.1  cmi-kinvey
karma                               1.4.1   1.4.1   1.7.0  cmi-kinvey
karma-chrome-launcher               2.0.0   2.0.0   2.2.0  cmi-kinvey
karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter    0.2.3   0.2.3   1.3.0  cmi-kinvey
ts-node                             2.0.0   2.0.0   3.1.0  cmi-kinvey
tslint                              4.5.1   4.5.1   5.4.3  cmi-kinvey
typescript                          2.2.2   2.2.2   2.3.4  cmi-kinvey`

These packages are the ones listed in my `devDependencies`, looking at my `dependencies` packages it has packages such as `"@angular/common": "^4.1.0"`, where the latest version is 4.2.4 at the time of this post. So why isn't npm showing my non Devdependencies as out of date?

Comment: Mika, 

What is the npm version you are usng? Can you try the latest v3.1.0? Also please try "npm outdated -g" and see if it shows 'dependencies' packages.

-Pranav, Kinvey

Comment: Hi Pranav, I am using npm v 5.0.3, I don't get any output when running `npm outdated -g`

Comment: Looks like npm outdated -g is bugged in v5.0.x for [now](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16840)